# Meteor JS — force cache clear for IE9?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor app, that loads "blank screen" on first load on IE9

[image: blank screen]

I then clear the cache

[image: clear cache]

Hit reload; then it loads.

[image: reload]

How can I avoid this occurance?